# Result of a soql parent to child soql request

Tags: soql, php, child-to-parent

I would want to know how I can display the result from a soql child to parent request?
**My request is:**

```
$query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, (select Retreat_Booking__c.Retreat__c from Retreat_Bookings__r)FROM Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);


$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
while($queryResult->current()->FirstName!='' || $queryResult->current()->LastName!='')
{
    echo $queryResult->current()->FirstName." ".$queryResult->current()->LastName." ".$queryResult->current()-> Retreat_Bookings__r->Retreat_Booking__c->Retreat__c." <BR/>";
    $queryResult->next();
}
```

The request works and display **FirstName** and **LastName** but not **Retreat__c**. I know the result in the 2nd select is a json and I tried many things, but nothing works.

Is somebody can help me please?
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what the JSON looks like when you perform a parent-child subquery through the API.

Here, I've queried

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account
```

where `Contacts` is the name of the child relationship. This illustrates the same paradigm you have, where you query from a parent to a child and include child properties.

```
{
  "totalSize": 1,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Account",
        "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/0013600001XXXXeAAI"
      },
      "Id": "0013600001XXXXeAAI",
      "Contacts": {
        "totalSize": 1,
        "done": true,
        "records": [
          {
            "attributes": {
              "type": "Contact",
              "url": "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/0033600001a27SFAAY"
            },
            "Id": "0033600001aXXXXAAY",
            "Name": "Tim Testerson"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the child objects are stored in a property of the parent object, and the name of that property is the **relationship name**. The content is a list of further sObject JSON structures just like the top-level response.

Further, relationships traversed from the child object are shown with another sObject JSON a property on the child object, with the name being the relationship name, and the content another sObject JSON structure.

In your case, the name of the child relationship is `Retreat_Bookings__r`. You should find more sObject records under that property in your response, in whatever fashion your PHP connector library translates them from the JSON.

When you do

```
echo $queryResult->current()->FirstName." ".$queryResult->current()->LastName." ".$queryResult->current()-> Retreat_Bookings__r->Retreat_Booking__c->Retreat__c." <BR/>";
```

It appears to me that your PHP is looking for an extra layer of indirection that isn't there, and failing to index into an array. Although I do not know PHP, I would expect something more like

```
$queryResult->current()->Retreat_Bookings__r[0]->Retreat__c
```

(where `[0]` is whatever syntax PHP uses for array indexing).